Create AppBundle from existing AutoLISP functions
I have a set of existing AutoLisp functions that I would like to package up as a plugin for the purpose of creating an AppBundle. I've seen several examples of this process (and what the PackageContents.xml should look like) for .dll plugins, but I cannot find any reference to the same process for AutoLISP code.
What are the Contents directory/file structure for this use case, and what should the corresponding PackageContents.xml look like?

I have answered similar query here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78402276/2919353
